# How can a Lambda function get the name of last modified file in given S3 path?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

So, I am looking to have a Lambda function (python) that will pick up the

1. file name
2. date & time of creation

of the last created file in that directory (having certain suffix)

My use-case requires something like this:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   S3Path="s3://my_bucket/my_dir/"
   
   file_name = get_file_name()
   created_datetime = get_datetime()
 
   if (current_datetime-created_datetime < 48 hours)
       #do something with "file_name"
```

Please help with the above required functions

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to "get the last created file".

You will need to list the objects with that Prefix, then programmatically determine the latest object by sorting the list. You can also add some code to check the Suffix of the Key.

Give it a try and let us know if you have any specific issues.